# RSocket with Webflux router

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, rsocket

I have an application with Spring boot webflux and exposing endpoints as below.

```
@Configuration
public class BusinessServiceConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private final RequestHandler reqHandler;

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> createUser() {
        return route(POST("/api/v1/user/create").and(contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)), reqHandler::createUser);
    }

}
```

Came across RSocket and it is promising. Planning to move to RSocket down the line.

Exposing end point with RSocket,

```
    @Controller
    public class RSocketController {
        @Autowired
        private final RequestService reqService;
    
        @MessageMapping("/api/v1/user/create")
        public Mono<String> createuser() {
            return reqService.createUser .....
        }
    }
```

Here, the way we expose API is totally different b/w Webflux and RSocket and it need some effort.

Is there anyway to just add RSocket without changing the way we expose end points?

Comment: No, as far as I know they are two distinct feature sets for web service calls vs message based systems.